# Why is $job.LastRunOutCome always "Failed"?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am using sqlps to run a backup job "Backup Something".

```
    Set-Location "SQLSERVER:\sql\$hostname\default\jobserver\jobs"
    $job = Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Backup Something"}
    $job.Start()
    Start-Sleep 5
    $job.LastRunDate
    $job.LastRunOutcome
```

Problem is, even when the job works and SQL Management Studio confirms that the backup job worked, .LastRunOutcome always returned "Failed".

Why?

Comment: Are you allowing the job to finish before checking its last outcome?

Comment: Good point. Maybe sleep 5 isn't enough any more.

Comment: Yes, I do. Outcome remains "Failed".

Comment: How about using the CurrentRunStatus rather than a sleep to determine when the job that you just kicked off finished or not? Something like `while ($job.CurrentRunStatus -ne "Idle") {sleep 5;} $job.LastRunOutCome;`